# Stretch a frame top to bottom tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to stretch the frame_0 (light blue colored) which is on the left from top to bottom of root_tk. Currently it is only limited height. You can see the image here. Please note that I dont want to use the place method due to some limitations. I only intend to use the grid method of widgets/ frames placement.

[image]

Below is my code. Please help.

```
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Light")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"

root_tk = customtkinter.CTk()  # create CTk window like you do with the Tk window (you can also use normal tkinter.Tk window)
root_tk.geometry("1000x1000")

root_tk.state("zoomed")

root_tk.title("CustomTkinter Test")

# endregion

# region Configure Custome Style of Combobox and Entry Widgets
style= ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('clam')
style.configure("TCombobox",arrowcolor="#1e1e1e")
style.map("TCombobox",fieldbackground=[("disabled", "1e1e1e")])
style.map("TEntry",fieldbackground=[("disabled", "1e1e1e")])
default_font = tkFont.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
default_font.configure(family="Tahoma")

# endregion

# region Text colors for labels
nlcolor = "#1e1e1e"                     # -------- Normal Label Text Color Dark Grey
hdcolor = "#EB3F3F"                     # -------- Headings Background Color (reddish)
# endregion

# Function to take data from GUI window and write to an excel file
mod_list =[]
dp_list=[]
mod_list2 =[]
sp_list=[]

def exelayout1():
    pass

# region Frames definition
frame_0 = Frame(root_tk,background="light blue")
frame_0.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="ns",rowspan=4)
# root_tk.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

frame_1 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(root_tk, corner_radius=15,fg_color="yellow")
frame_2 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(root_tk, corner_radius=15,fg_color="orange")
frame_3 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(root_tk, corner_radius=15,fg_color="yellow")
frame_4 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(root_tk, corner_radius=15,fg_color="orange")
frame_5 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(root_tk, corner_radius=15,fg_color="yellow")

frame_1.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10,sticky='n',ipadx=30)
frame_2.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=(0,10))
frame_3.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky='n')
frame_4.grid(row=0,column=2,pady=10,sticky='nws',rowspan=2)
frame_5.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky='nsw')
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366068/python-tkinter-rowspan-not-resizing-elements-correctly) answer your question?

Comment: Based on provided code, you need to add `root_tk.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)`.